# Tem como "esconder" uma chave de uma API antes de colocar o projeto no GitHub?

Tags: api, front-end, github, commit

Estou querendo commitar um projeto, mas não queria que minha key ficasse a amostra no meu escopo. Queria saber se tem como colocar minha key lá no projeto. Pensei em .gitignore ou o .env, lembro que usava algo assim, mas não tenho certeza. Ps: é um projeto frontend.

Answer (score -4):

para isso você deve criar um arquivo gitgnore e lá vc coloca os dados que deseja que o git ignore.